# Combine two maps to create a third map in Terraform 0.12

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a requirement to do some complicated merging of input data in Terraform 0.12. I can't figure out if it's possible, but maybe I'm just doing something wrong.

I have two variables:

```hcl
variable "ebs_block_device" {
  description = "Additional EBS block devices to attach to the instance"
  type        = list(map(string))
  default     = [
    {
      device_name = "/dev/sdg"
      volume_size = 5
      volume_type = "gp2"
      delete_on_termination = false
    },
    {
      device_name = "/dev/sdh"
      volume_size = 5
      volume_type = "gp2"
      delete_on_termination = false
    }
  ]
}

variable "mount_point" {
  description = "Mount point to use"
  type = list(string)
  default = ["/data", "/home"]
}
```

I want to then combine these sources inside a template like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
%{for e in merged ~}
mkfs -t xfs ${e.device_name}
mkdir -p ${e.mount_point}
mount ${e.device_name} ${e.mount_point}
%{endfor}
```

Where `merged` would contain the combined data.

It seems that only simple for loops are supported in the template language, so doing the merge in there seems to be out of the question.

So, I assume the data munging needs to happen in the DSL. But, I would need to do this:

- iterate over the list of ebs_block_devices, tracking the index (like `enumerate()` in Python, or `each.with_index` in Ruby)
- get the corresponding element from the list of mount_points
- add these to a resultant map.

My problem, specifically, is that there doesn't seem to be any equivalent of Python's `enumerate` function, and this prevents me tracking the index. If there was, I imagine I could do something like this:

```hcl
merged = [for index, x in enumerate(var.ebs_block_device): {
  merge(x, {mount_point => var.mount_point[index]})
}]
```

Is such a data transformation as I am trying to do here currently possible in Terraform? And if not possible, what is the preferred alternative implementation?

Comment: I think `mount_point` would need to be a map to utilize the `merge` function here. As it is, I notice that both types are `list` as primitives, so maybe iterate through one list and then access the element maps of the first variable and elements of the second variable by index. That would work for you, but have the drawback that you would need to create a safeguard that the length of both variables is equal.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, no I tested in Python, and the code would work, if Terraform had `enumerate()`, see [this](https://gist.github.com/alexharv074/42fd3ecbdfd7852e427545d8de5ff8d7) Gist. What you're proposing is exactly what I want to do, except there seems no way to access the index without enumerate.

Comment: Are you trying to mount these volumes as part of `user_data`? Can't you do something like http://www.sanjeevnandam.com/blog/ec2-mount-ebs-volume-during-launch-time ? Probably you'll have to use a loop-template, like described in https://medium.com/ovni/terraform-templating-and-loops-9a88c0786c5c

Comment: Thank you @aderubaru but the question is really about how to merge the data. I can see ways to do this without merging the data but I think what I want to do ought to be possible. I raised a feature request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out this is in fact possible like this:

```hcl
variable "ebs_block_device" {
  description = "Additional EBS block devices to attach to the instance"
  type        = list(map(string))
  default     = [
    {
      device_name = "/dev/sdg"
      volume_size = 5
      volume_type = "gp2"
      delete_on_termination = false
    },
    {
      device_name = "/dev/sdh"
      volume_size = 5
      volume_type = "gp2"
      delete_on_termination = false
    }
  ]
}

variable "mount_point" {
  description = "Mount point to use"
  type = list(string)
  default = ["/data", "/home"]
}

output "merged" {
  value = [
    for index, x in var.ebs_block_device:
    merge(x, {"mount_point" = var.mount_point[index]})
  ]
}
```

With thanks to HashiCorp support.